# Euler method uniform convergence

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

I have a question for you guys. 
Given a differential equation 
$$\dot{x}=f(x)\qquad x\in\mathbb{R}^n$$
on a compact interval $[0,T]$. If one considers for every $k\in\mathbb{N}$, the Euler's polygonal approximations obtained by partitioning the interval $[0,T]$ in subintervals of length $\frac{T}{k}$. This procedure gives rise to a sequence of piecewise affine functions,  say $\{\varphi_k\}$. Now, it is known that, under suitable hypothesis, there exists a subsequence of $\{\varphi_k\}$ that uniformly converges to a continuous function on $[0,T]$. My question is, can we prove, perhaps under further hypothesis, that the whole sequence $\{\varphi_k\}$ uniformly converges to something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if the ODE satisfies the Lipschitz condition so that there exists a unique exact solution, then the Euler polygon of stepsize $h$ has an error of size $\sim \frac{M}L·(e^{Lt}-1)h$ at time $t$. $M$ is a bound on $f$ and $L$ is the Lipschitz constant of $f$.

Comment: I see, what about having $f$ discontinuous?

Comment: Then there does not need to exist a solution. See for instance the discussion of $\ddot x+x=-a·\operatorname{sign}(\dot x)$, $a>0$, in http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1201234/115115

Comment: I perfectly agree with you. I don't care about obtaining a solution, I just want to be sure that by making $h$ smaller and smaller, the sequence approaches uniformly a certain function, that's all.

Comment: In that example you reach a point where the solution stops without reaching a stationary point. Perhaps easier to explore is $\dot x = -\operatorname{sign}(x)$. There is no solution to approximate.

Comment: Exactly, but if you build a polygonal to the latter, with $x(0)=0$, this converges uniformly to the null function, though the considered differential equation does not admit any solution from $x(0)=0$.

Comment: Granted, you get convergence in $C^0$. And any $L^1_{loc}$ vector field is $L^1_{loc}$ close to continuous vector fields, giving solutions per Peano.. However, for solutions to differential equations one would prefer convergence in $C^1$. Which you get for Lipschitz ODE.

Comment: I see, so you confirm me that uniform convergence is ensured?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22991/discussion-between-francesco-and-lutzl).