# Analytic approximation of $\ddot x+\gamma sign(\dot x)+x=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to find an analytic approximation to this non-linear differential equation.
$$
\ddot x+\gamma sign(\dot x)+x=0
$$
 $\gamma$ is a very small parameter. The solution I am getting is 
$$
x(t)=a_{0}e^{\frac{-2\gamma t}{\pi}}\cos t
$$ 
When I compare this to a numerically approximated solution in Mathematica it is clear that my approximation is incorrect.

[image: 1]

I can't seem to figure out what term is responsible for the ending behavior or the numerically calculated blue line. The orange line is my approximation. 
Can anyone help show me where I went wrong. Any help would be appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [solution of a ODE with a funtion of $\dot{x}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1201234/solution-of-a-ode-with-a-funtion-of-dotx)