# special finite time models

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory

based on [Haimo](https://doi.org/10.1137/0324047) manuscript the below equation is finite time:

$$
    \dot x(t) = - {\rm sign}(x(t)) 
\tag1
$$
and based on the manuscript many other equation are proposed, such as terminal sliding mode, fast terminal sliding mode, ... controllers in control systems theory which is not main problem for me, here. infact the -sign(x(t)) term is as control input. I want to have finite time control input which its integral is zero.

in an application like cascade control, integral of the right side of the equation (1), ${\rm sign}(x(t))$, is used which should reaches zero after time.

As you know and based on [Haimo](https://doi.org/10.1137/0324047), finite time variables $x(t)$ do not spin around the origin, meaning its sign often is not changed and the variable reaches origin in finite time with constant slope.

How can I trigger the equation variable to force the integral of ${\rm sign}(x(t))$ function to zero value?

in other word we should trigger the variable, $x(t)$, to spin around origin and make $\int {\rm sign}(x(t))\,dt$ over time, zero.

Comment: Hello! On Stackexchange, it's generally good practice to write all the details in your question inside the text of your question, and not rely too much on links and pictures to outside material.

Comment: Could you please clarify what do you mean by "trigger the equation variable"? The dynamics $\dot{x} = - \operatorname{sgn}(x)$ is autonomous, there is no control input.

Comment: You also get a sudden stop with oscillating sign, see the equation $\ddot x+a{\rm sign}(\dot x)+x=0$. You get an approximation with infinite run-time if you replace the sign function with a steep sigmoid function, like $\tanh(\Omega u)$ for some fairly large $\Omega$.

Comment: For additional background, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3298459/sliding-motion-and-fillippov-system and links. Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54767096/odeint-returns-wrong-results for a slightly more interesting example, in the same way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60309851/unsure-about-how-to-use-event, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63641982/avoiding-plotting-odes-divergenet-solution

Comment: thank you @Albert, I have modified the text.

Comment: you are right @Arastas. I meant by adding a term in right side of the equation. I worse finite time property but force the finite time control input (-Ksign(x)) integral zero.

Comment: Thank you @LutzLehmann very much. the links you have sent are great. but I can't understand what you said in your first comment. is the equation you have recommended finite time?

Comment: I have edited the post:
'infact the -sign(x(t)) term is as control input. I want to have finite time control input which its integral is zero.'

Comment: Yes, the solutions are spirals that stop after a finite time with no sensible continuation as a strong solution. The weak or gliding solution goes on to converge to zero.

Comment: great @LutzLehmann! , can you give me more information about the equation, like its name or a manuscript about it, I took instability in some value of 'a'. but it's spiral and awesome for me...!!! :)

Comment: This is from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1201234/solution-of-a-ode-with-a-function-of-dotx and linked problems. It should be a standard example in texts about "tame" discontinuous ODE.

Comment: thank you @LutzLehmann, you got me a valuable aid, the right keyword.